# How is compiler inferring type on a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I have a `Storage` class:

```java
class Storage<E> {
    void add(E e) {
        // add element
    };

    void addAll(Iterable<? extends E> src) {
        for (E e : src)
            add(e);
    }
}
```

There are two classes where class `Child` `extends` `Parent`:

`Parent`

```java
class Parent implements Comparable<Parent> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Parent o) {
        return 0; // some comparison logic
    }
}
```

`Child`

```java
class Child extends Parent {

}
```

Driver class:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /******** CASE 1 *********/
        Storage<Parent> ds = new Storage<Parent>();
        ds.add(new Parent());
        
        ds.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Parent()));
        
        // Type params are invariant.
        // But List<Child> is possible due to bounded wildcard type on addAll
        ds.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Child())); // Makes sense
        
        /******** CASE 2 *********/
        List<Child> t = Arrays.asList();
        max(t);
        
    }
    
    static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list) {
        return null; // Return null so code can compile
    }
}
```

Because `Storage` is a generic class, the operations on its method makes sense; I get how case 1 is working.

In case 2, with above signature of `max` in `GenericTest`, I get the compilation error:

`The method max(List<T>) in the type GenericTest is not applicable for the arguments (List<Child>)`

I understand that `Comparable<Child>` is not a sub-type of `Comparable<Parent>` (Typed params are invariant).

So, I updated signature to

```java
// update Comparable<T> to Comparable<? super T>
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> list)
```

Now, the code compiles and inferred signature is

`<Child> Child GenericTest.max(List<Child> list)` 
This makes sense.

When I update the signature to

```java
// update List<T> to List<? extends T>
static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list)
```

the code compiles and inferred signature is

`<Parent> Parent GenericTest.max(List<? extends Parent> list)`

I couldn't understand how updating `List<T>` to `List<? extends T>` made the compiler infer the type `Parent`.

I mean, for a generic method (on which there is direct invocation using type `Child`), how did `? extends T` helped compiler refer the parent class of `Child`? Note that this signature has `Comparable<T>` (and not `Comparable<? super T`).

Isn't `extends` about a type which is `T` itself and its sub-classes?

**Edit:** 
Java 8 comes with updated type-inference rules.
The below is sufficient for type-inference in Java 8 and later, but not for Java 7 and below:

```java
static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list)
```

It gives compilation error:

`Bound mismatch: The generic method max(List<? extends T>) of type GenericTest is not applicable for the arguments (List<Child>). The inferred type Child is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>>`

The signaure

```java
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void max(List<T> list)
```

is sufficient for Java 7, though.

Comment: downvoters are not required to explain themselves. It wasn't me btw, and I can't see why this would be downvoted, but you aren't entitled to an explanation and the downvoter is unlikely to see your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things clearer, the class `Child`:

- `extends Parent`
- `implements Comparable<Parent>`

###### 1) `static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list)`

- `T` is `Child`
- fails because `Child` is not a `Comparable<Child>`

###### 2) `static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> list)`

- `T` is `Child`
- `?` is `Parent`
- it works because `Child implements Comparable<Parent super Child>`

###### 3) `static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list)`

- `T` is `Parent`
- `?` is `Child`
- it works because `Child extends Parent implements Comparable<Parent>`

Here in case 3), finding a valid `T` class can be seen as: *"find the first super class of `Child` that implements a `Comparable` of itself"*.
As in case 1), it cannot be `Child` because it is not a `Comparable<Child>`.
The first (and only) super class of `Child` that implements `Comparable` of itself is `Parent`.

> I couldn't understand how updating `List<T>` to `List<? extends T>` made the compiler infer the type `Parent`.

- `List<T>` forces `T` to be `Child`
- `List<? extends T>` forces `?` to be `Child`, not `T`

Comment: The explanation makes sense, Tigger. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To me it fails with both JDK 8 and JDK 7, so I don't see the inconsistency which you describe between those JDks

JDK 8 compilation

[image]

JDK 7 compilation

[image]

As to why it fails it is called **PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)**

The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64888058/7237884) has helped me a lot to understand it.

> If you say <? extends SomeType>, then you wanna describe a ‘box’ that
> is the same size or smaller than the ‘SomeType’ box.

Taking in consideration the aforementioned, when you described max method as

```
 static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list)
```

With your declaration `List<? extends T> list` you need a container of the same or smaller than T. Which could be Child as you use it.

```
List<Child> t = Arrays.asList();
```

so this should have compiled.

However the return type is of `<T extends Comparable<T>> T` which then is translated into `Child extends Comparable<Child>`.

Java however has a limitation that prevents you from implementing the same generic interface (in your case Comparable) with different type parameters.

That is why the error says

```
required: java.util.List<? extends T>   
found: java.util.List<Child>   reason: inferred type does not
conform to declared bound(s)
inferred: Child
bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<Child>
```

[image]

### **Solution**

You should have declared the return type with `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

> Contra-variance: ? super T ( the family of all types that are
> supertypes of T) - a wildcard with a lower bound. T is the lower-most
> class in the inheritance hierarchy.
> [from a previous answer on PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634364/7237884)

In that case it would have compiled as it would have set the bound to `Comparable<Parent>`.

Comment: *To me it fails with both JDK 8 and JDK 7, * That's weird. I rechecked and saw this issue. The type-inference did get [updated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) in Java 8. Thanks for the link, that's helpful.